# How to pass data between fields in Oracle APEX 5.1?

Tags: oracle-apex

This is a VERY basic question. Sorry for not providing any code I have NO IDEA how to even start tackling the problem
I have lets say two fields... One is a date selector field and the other a regular text field. What I want is when I select a date (or type a date), the value comes in the second field... Just that...

I'm on APEX 5.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated that the second item is a text field, you could do this with the help of a dynamic action that sets the value of the second item when there is a change in the value of the first item ( date field).

The following would be the steps, if you are using component view:

- Create Dynamic Action

  - When

    - Event : Change
    - Selection : Item(s)
    - Item : First Page Item
    - Condition : is not null
  - True Action

    - Action : Set Value
    - Fire on Page Load: No
    - Set Type: You can choose how you want to set the value of the second item on the page.

If you have the flexibility to change the second item to be a select list and you have a list of values that goes with a date, you could do this much simpler, with a **Cascading LOV**

- On Second Item's - Under List of Values section

  - Cascading LOV Parent Item(s) : First Item
  - Page Items to Submit: First Item
  - List of Values definition:  Here you can define the query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I worked but with an something unexpected.... In `Field2`,  I get `16&#x2F;01&#x2F;18` when the selected date of `Field1` is displayed as `16/01/18`....

Comment: I believe it must be due to the format mask on the first page item( date field). Did you try doing TO_DATE in the PL/SQL expression ? Or you could change the format mask on the first item as well.

Comment: I tried both... date field format mask in is `DD/MM/YYYY` and I used in the PL/SQL expression `TO_DATE(:Field1,'DD/MM/YYYY')`. It still does not display properly... Formatting `field2` did not change anything also

Comment: When you say it does not display properly, what exactly do you mean? Are you running into an ajax error or its still showing you in the format you posted above or its displaying in DD-MON-YY format?

Comment: No Ajax error... I get `16&#x2F;01&#x2F;18` in `field2` when I pick `16/01/2018`  in `field1`.... `Field1` also displays `16/01/2018`. As far as display in `field1`, format works as expected

Comment: Ok Problem solve..... I was because I was using `DD/MM/YYYY`.  When I used `DD-MM-YYYY` it worked properly... / (slash) is triggering unexpected behavior...  Thank you mate

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this, probably the easiest way is as follows.

Assume your two items are `P1_ITEM1` and `P1_ITEM2`.

Create a `dynamic action` which fires `on change` of item `P1_ITEM1`.

The true action of this should be action:`set value`, set type:`PL/SQL Expression`, item:`:P1_ITEM2`, items to submit `P1_ITEM1`.